# set numpy array value to a constant value except for the element on the edges

Tags: python, numpy

How to set all the values of a numpy array that aren't on an edge of the array to a constant value. 
I've already searched around but got nothing work.

Comment: please give an example of desired inputs and outputs, and some of the things you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use array indexing `[1:-1]` to refer to the inner array. For example

```py
    a = np.zeros((5,5))   # Create an array of all zeros
    print(a)
    # [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
    #  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
    #  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
    #  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
    #  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
    a[1:-1, 1:-1] = np.full((3,3), 7) # Assign the inner array to be a constant array of 7
    print(a)
    # [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
    #  [0. 7. 7. 7. 0.]
    #  [0. 7. 7. 7. 0.]
    #  [0. 7. 7. 7. 0.]
    #  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```